# How to estimate affine transformation matrix in skimage?

Tags: transformation, scikit-image, affinetransform

I need to transform triangle piece of image (right up picture, red) to another position (right up picture, green). Following [this example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_geometric.html#parameter-estimation) I'm trying to estimate affine matrix and apply it for transformation. But the result is not right (left down picture).

In the code below I'm trying to transform from `uv_coords_src` (right up picture, red) to `uv_coords_dst` (right up picture, green)

```
import numpy as np

from skimage import io
from skimage import draw
from skimage import transform
from skimage import img_as_float
from skimage import data

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

uv_coords_src = np.array([[239,287], [101,340], [96,196]])
uv_coords_dst = np.array([[253,179], [170,70], [263,46]])

img = img_as_float(data.chelsea())

mask = draw.polygon2mask(image_shape=img.shape, polygon=uv_coords_src)
mask_out = draw.polygon2mask(image_shape=img.shape, polygon=uv_coords_dst)
masked_image = img * mask
masked_image_out = img * (mask + mask_out)

tform3 = transform.AffineTransform()
tform3.estimate(uv_coords_src, uv_coords_dst)
warped = transform.warp(masked_image, tform3, output_shape=img.shape)

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(masked_image_out, cmap='gray')
ax3.imshow(warped, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

Please, help me to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems `skimage.transform.warp()` does not work properly..

I made a transformation via `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform()`

```
import numpy as np

from skimage import io
from skimage import draw
from skimage import transform
from skimage import img_as_float
from skimage import data

import scipy

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

uv_coords_src = np.array([[239,287], [101,340], [96,196]])
uv_coords_dst = np.array([[253,179], [170,70], [263,46]])

img = img_as_float(data.chelsea())

mask = draw.polygon2mask(image_shape=img.shape, polygon=uv_coords_src)
mask_out = draw.polygon2mask(image_shape=img.shape, polygon=uv_coords_dst)
masked_image = img * mask
masked_image_out = img * (mask + mask_out)

tform3 = transform.AffineTransform()
tform3.estimate(uv_coords_src, uv_coords_dst)
warped0 = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(masked_image[:, :, 0], np.linalg.inv(tform3.params))
warped1 = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(masked_image[:, :, 1], np.linalg.inv(tform3.params))
warped2 = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(masked_image[:, :, 2], np.linalg.inv(tform3.params))

warped = np.dstack([warped0, warped1, warped2])

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(masked_image_out, cmap='gray')
ax3.imshow(warped, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```